# Strongloop/Loopback: How to login if multiple models extend built-in User model

Tags: authentication, model, strongloop

I've just started to develop with Strongloop framework and I've seen that you can extend basic built-in models, such as the User model. E.g.: a Patient model may extend User model. Therefore, basic user information and services will be automatic extended from User model and it will be possible to request for login, logout etc. through the Patient model (e.g.: Patient.login(credentials)).

However, if I have multiple models that extend from User model (e.g.: Physicion, Admin and Patient), how to execute remote methods from the User model without knowing which one of the three models do I have to execute? For instance, if I have a Patient account, I can request Patient.login(credentials), and the Strongloop will make the login correctly. On the other hand, at the login page, I don't know if a Patient or a Physicion user has typed his/her credentials. So, I don't know which login method do I have to invoke: if Patient.login or Physicion.login. The remote method User.login does not work in my case. How to request for login without knowing the type of user beforehand?

Answer (score 2):

If you are extending the User model, it shouldn't matter as they will all look for the same auth token in the DB and execute the same exact code in `loopback/common/models/User.js`, they will just be named differently.

But in the larger picture, you should keep track of what type of user you're dealing with by their identifying information (email etc) and not by the submodel/class of model they will be accessing. You should know this before you make the proper call.

Take a look at the Role model and RoleMapping model. You could for instance create Patient, Physician, and Admin Roles, and then map them to Users, then use a single model (User) for logging in.

What if you have a physician who is also a patient? Or a physician who is also an Admin? With roles you can manage this with a single User model, and then know which sub model to use.

Comment: But, what if patient, doctor and admin has totally different fields? Would it be proper if all these data is stored in a single User table?

Comment: @Anoop.P.A Yes, one way would be to put everything into a massive User model and allow nulls for fields that do not apply. But by saying "totally different fields" if you mean they will share no fields in common whatsoever (not even name, email, etc.), which is pretty rare, then yes, they should be separate models. But I recommend extending the User model (with Person) for this too since you can't easily modify User since it's part of loopback. Extending User gives you authentication and common stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Been working with IBM-StrongLoop Loopback 3 for a while now, decided to build up this starter for building multi-user models api. Do check it out. 
[Multi-User API Starter](https://github.com/codekeyz/loopback-multirole-api-starter). It's absolutely free to use and also has been built to do all the heavy lifting for you.

All you need to do is to let your CustomUser Models i.e Patient, Doctor, Physician etc.. extend BaseUser which is present in the starter. For Role Based permission in ACL, you can check up on an example usage of the starter, [Loopback Multi-User Based Auth and Role-Based ACL](https://github.com/codekeyz/loopback-multirole-example) All that's all...